# Replace attribute name inside specific tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

In my new Wordpress theme, I'm going to use a lazyload library that requires me use the `data-src` attribute instead of `src`. Since I want to preserve the old content as-is, I'd like to replace the attributes using a Wordpress function. What would be the replace pattern that ignores the order of attributes and is limited to `img` and `iframe` tags?

Comment: can u use jquery prior to the lazy load?

Comment: I'd prefer to use a Wordpress' function to replace the attributes, that's why I was looking for a PHP solution

Comment: Oh then maybe tag or say wordpress as no one would have any clue this has anything to do with wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parser, this is safer than using regular expressions on html.

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument(1.0, 'utf-8');
    $doc->loadHTML("html string........"); //replace with your html string
    $iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");

    foreach($iframes as $iframe)
    {
        $iframe->setAttribute("data-src", $iframe->getAttribute("src") );
        $iframe->removeAttribute("src"); // optional, delete if not wanted.
    }

    foreach($imgs as $img)
    {
        $img->setAttribute("data-src", $img->getAttribute("src") );
        $img->removeAttribute("src"); // optional, delete if not wanted.
    }

    $editedHTML = $doc.saveHTML();
```